# DialogFlow API V1, intent is not available

Tags: dialogflow-es

One of the intents that is displayed correctly in the chat-bot (the text is there) has got empty inside. We need to change the text in there but can't.

http://prntscr.com/pn1yed

With training phrase, the intent is not found. The screenshot above.

Comment: Please state exactly what you are asking. Do you need to clarify why the intent is empty or do you need to know how to control attributes of the intent?

Comment: We need to change the intent but it is empty inside (though it was not) while the chat-bot gives the text when triggered. The problem is in the chat-bot interface, not API. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow API v1 is shutdown from 23rd OCT 2019.
You will have to switch to DialogFlow Api V2.

[Here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide) is a migration guide, you can migrate to DF API V2 using this official guide.